# how to access image data on React-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I would like to take image data (RGBA) from react-three-fiber

like this code on HTML

```
var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
myCanvas.width = texture.image.width; 
myCanvas.height = texture.image.height;
var myCanvasContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d"); // Get canvas 2d context
myCanvasContext.drawImage(texture.image, 0, 0); // Draw the texture
var texels = myCanvasContext.getImageData(0,0, width, height); // Read the texels/pixels back
```

However, I cannot access Canvas to drawImage or getImageData.

```
const ref = React.useRef();
    
React.useEffect(() => {
        if (ref) {
       //error
       ref.current.getContext("2d");
        }
      }, []);
    
    <Canvas
      dpr={[1, 1.5]} //pixelRatio
      ref={ref}
    >
    <Particles />
    </Canvas>
```

and I tried to use useThree. there is no method to get imageData

```
  const {
    gl,
  } = useThree();
```

lastly, I tired to get an image using useLoader as a texture

```
 const map = useLoader(TextureLoader, "/scroll_images/img1.jpg");
```

so, how can I get the imageData?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, try `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`. Refs are not actually populated until the first DOM render happened. Unlike `useEffect`, `useLayoutEffect` waits until this occurred.

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current.getContext("2d"); // <-- hopefully doesnt error
}, []);
```

In your second example I think its because you need to pass `gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}` prop to your `Canvas`. Then you can use `gl.domElement.toDataURL('image/png')` or similar.

Comment: thank you for your comment! even if I try useLayoutEffect, `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.` , `The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Canvas)> component:` errors occurred. Not only that, after passing `gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}`, I could get some data about image but not I want. I want to access the image's pixel data like  Uint8ClampedArray (RGBA)

Comment: Hmmm. What about `gl.domElement.getContext("2d")`

Comment: :( it returns null...